# pandas merge DataFrames like magnetic thing

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2015-01-01', '2015-01-10', '2015-01-11', '2015-01-12'], 'a': [1,2,3,4]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2015-01-01', '2015-01-05', '2015-01-11'], 'b': [10,20,30]})

df = df1.merge(df2, on=['date'], how='outer')

df = df.sort_values('date')

print df
```

"like magnetic thing" may not be a good expression in title. I will explain below.

I want record from df2 to match the first record of df1 which date is greater or equals df2's. For example, I want df2's '2015-01-05' to match df1's '2015-01-10'.

I cannot achieve it by simply merging them in `inner`, `outer`, `left` way. Though, the above result is very close to what I want.

```
     a        date     b
0  1.0  2015-01-01  10.0
4  NaN  2015-01-05  20.0
1  2.0  2015-01-10   NaN
2  3.0  2015-01-11  30.0
3  4.0  2015-01-12   NaN
```

How can achieve this from what I have done or in some other ways from scratch?

```
     a        date     b
0  1.0  2015-01-01  10.0
1  2.0  2015-01-10  20.0
2  3.0  2015-01-11  30.0
3  4.0  2015-01-12   NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

making sure your dates are dates

```
df1.date = pd.to_datetime(df1.date)
df2.date = pd.to_datetime(df2.date)
```

***`numpy`***
`np.searchsorted`

```
ilocs = df1.date.values.searchsorted(df2.date.values)
df1.loc[df1.index[ilocs], 'b'] = df2.b.values

df1

   a       date     b
0  1 2015-01-01  10.0
1  2 2015-01-10  20.0
2  3 2015-01-11  30.0
3  4 2015-01-12   NaN
```

***`pandas`***
[`pd.merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.0/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html) gets you really close

```
pd.merge_asof(df1, df2)

   a       date   b
0  1 2015-01-01  10
1  2 2015-01-10  20
2  3 2015-01-11  30
3  4 2015-01-12  30
```

Comment: I'm determined to have both.  Not sure if it's possible yet... but trying

Comment: Super, numpy solution get desired output.